# Umbraco extensions - list unpublished pages

Tags: umbraco

I've been looking and looking in Umbracos web extensions,
(https://our.umbraco.org/projects/?category=Backoffice%20extensions) but I can't seem to find any plugin/extension where you can see a list of unpublished pages in Umbracos admin view.

If you happen to know anything about this please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually umbraco has the option to publish and unpublish the pages. Unpublished one are the one with font color more pale than published. What do you mean to see a list of unpublished pages ?

Comment: Hello and thank you for reply.
What I mean is that I want to see as a new tab in the Umbraco admin mode, a list of pages that is unpublished

Comment: Oh man for umbraco its so difficult to find such a specific extension. Of course if you spend money you can find something but believe me its a waste of time. You better start building something of your own.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of this one, but it requires you to do a search/filter every time... http://soetemansoftware.nl/bulkmanager

Comment: Thank you Jannik for reply! I will look into this :)

Comment: This one is pretty darn neat too, BTW: our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/the-dashboard (and please remember to accept answers if they answer your question ;-) )

Comment: Thank you @Jannik Anker :) Ofoucrse I will flag it green if I think its correct :)